# How to authenticate both PC and application installed in it with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I have a desktop where there is an application installed and few applications can be accessed via browser as well. I would like to authenticate one time user login ( that is 1st login to PC) using Azure AD so that same authentication can work for any application( both desktop app or web app). I think it's kind of SSO, but not very sure as PC authentication will be done at 1st place.

Note, this could be a multi user PC. That is individuals need to login with their own credentials. How can this be achieved ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve SSO to cloud resources with [Azure AD registered devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-register) and SSO to both cloud and on-premises resources with [Azure AD joined devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join).